# List() deprecated for Loop

Tags: flutter, dart, deprecated

Hej!,

so I found that List() is deprecated. How can I initiate the List and run for the length of my _data.length and fill it with my json _data[I] now?

Greetings
Noob TopTickTom

```
class WakeProvider {
  Client client = Client();

  fetchFeatures() async {
    final response = await client.get('$_root/.json');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);
      List _data = parsedJson['employee'];
      List _result = List();
      for (int i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
        _result.add(EmployeeModel.fromJson(_data[i]));
      }
      return _result;
    } else {
      throw NullThrownError();
    }
  }
```

Comment: nvm is fixed it with this: ```  List _result = []; ```

Comment: Go ahead and add an answer. Never know whom it might help one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with initialising the new way after reading the documentation... :-)

```
 List _result = [];
```

Comment: Please note that `List _result = List();` will throw away any type information since you are just creating a `List<dynamic>` where Dart can no longer make any guarantees about what types you are inserting and getting out of the list. In your example, what you properly want is instead: `final _result = <EmployeeModel>[]`.